# receive_message_chain and smelly code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am testing my controller and there is a string that produces AR query:
`current_user.providers.find(params[:id])`. I need it to return exactly the object I test, otherwise, the controller gets a reference that differs from the one I have in spec and some stubs like `allow(provider).to receive(:recreate)` do not work.

The only way I found to do this is using `receive_message_chain` like this:
`allow(provider.user).to receive_message_chain(:providers, :find => provider)`. But rspec documentation [says](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-6/docs/working-with-legacy-code/message-chains) to consider using `receive_message_chain` as code that smells.
In addition, I think later I may need to call `current_user.providers.find(otherid)` with another id, to get another object, so that would not work for me anymore.

Is there any way to do it better? I have already managed to avoid `allow_any_instance_of`, that is also considered as smelly, so I believe there is a way to avoid this too, I just can't see it.
If there's no, I at least wonder if there any way to add something like `with` to `receive_message_chain`?

===========

I just trying to test an `update` method of my controller.

```
# app/controllers/restream/facebooks_controller.rb
class Restream::FacebooksController < Restream::BaseController
  def update
    current_user.providers.find(params[:id])

    if @fb.update_attributes(facebook_params)
      if event_changed?
        @fb.recreate
      else
        @fb.update
      end
      redirect_to restreams_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
end

#spec/controllers/restream/facebooks_controller_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

describe Restream::FacebooksController do
  let!(:facebook) { create(:restream_facebook) }
  let!(:restream) { facebook.restream }

  before do
    login(restream.user)
  end

  describe '#update' do
    let!(:params_hash)  { {
        :title          => facebook.title,
        :privacy        => facebook.privacy,
        :destination    => facebook.destination,
        :destination_id => facebook.destination_id,
        :description    => facebook.description
      } }
    let!(:request_hash) { {
          :restream_facebook  => params_hash,
          :id                 => facebook.id
      } }

    before do
      allow(facebook.user).
        to receive_message_chain(:providers, :find => facebook)
      allow(facebook).to receive(:update)
      allow(facebook).to receive(:recreate)
    end

    context 'updates' do
      it 'title' do
        params_hash[:title] = SecureRandom.hex(2)
        post :update, request_hash

        expect(facebook.reload.title).to eq params_hash[:title]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Will your controller work the same by removing `current_user` from the chain? `Provider.find(params[:id])` That way you have less chained methods and more simple code to test. I don't think the chain of `current_user.providers.find` is doing more than just `Provider.find`.

Comment: I can't remove `current_user` permanently. And I don't want to have a string like `if Rails.env.test?` also. Or you mean I can do it other way?

Comment: The controller method you reference in the first sentence of your post, I would suggest replacing with `Provider.find(params[:id]) as it should work the same as having `current_user` tacked on to it. If it produces the same behavior for you, then your test code seems like it would be easier to run due to less method chaining. It would probably help to edit your post with more code examples because I could be way off in my assumptions.

Comment: I can easily add more code samples, just don't know what exactly.
I've tried to use `allow(Provider).to receive(:find).with(provider.id).and_return provider` but that didn't work for some reason.

Comment: Could you add the controller method you are testing?

Answer (score 0):

`receive_messaged_chain` can be a smell, but using doubles when testing controller is much bigger stink.

Since you didn't provide any controller action code, I would give you general examples:

```
def destroy
   @provider = current_user.providers.find(params[:id])
   @provider.delete
end
```

Don't test if `delete` method was called. Test if the object disappeared from the DB, for example:

```
let(:current_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let!(:provider) { FactoryGirl.create(:provider, user: current_user } 
it do
  delete :destroy, id: provider.id
  expect(Provider.find(provider.id).to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound) # writing from memory, don't remember exactly how the exception is called
end

# or

it do
  expect { delete :destroy }
   .to change{ Provider.where(id: provider.id).count }.from(1).to(0)
end
```

And so on. Generally, you want to use doubles as the last resort solution. Think of ways to test your code in terms of real effects it does, not the methods it's calling. This applies to any integration tests (which controllers are). If you're writing unit tests and need isolation - then mock stuff to achieve this isolation.

Comment: In fact, I was testing `update` method and wanted to sure that updates are made to the object I need. I will provide some code now. But I think I just realize I could just test not `facebook.title`, but `Restream::Facebook.find(facebook.id).title`. I guess so.

Comment: I also realized that I definitely want to stub (or I can call it wrong, I'm new to these words still) `initialize` and `recreate` methods for `facebook`. And if I won't kind of 'replace' result of `provider.find` I will need to use `allow_any_instance_of` to stub those methods. So I still need to replace what it finds with what I need.

Comment: @Ngoral In that case you're right. Stub finder method (Something.find or something,providers.find with receive_message_chain) to return a mock you set up in your test and check on that mock that some method was called. I think using `receive_message_chain` is not a big deal here as long as you're clear what you are testing.

Comment: @Ngoral Using stubs sometimes make your test brittle (somebody adds sorting to the message chain and you have a false negative) so it's better to stub `abstractions` like `ProvidersFinder.find_for_user(current_user)`. But you trade in code complexity and you have to decide what you need and want in your codebase